# Any suggestions to find a non recursive formula for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have these elements in a set $R$,
$$\{r_i\ /\ i=1,2,3,\dots,2n  \}\in R$$
And we define:
$$a(1)=r_1+r_2$$
$$a(2)=\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4$$
$$a(3)=\frac{\left(\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4\right)\cdot r_5}{\left(\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4\right)+r_5}+r_6$$
$$a(4)=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4\right)\cdot r_5}{\left(\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4\right)+r_5}+r_6\right)\cdot r_7}{\left(\frac{\left(\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4\right)\cdot r_5}{\left(\frac{(r_1+r_2)\cdot r_3}{(r_1+r_2)+ r_3}+r_4\right)+r_5}+r_6\right)+r_7}+r_8$$
Generally,
$$a(n+1)=\frac{a(n)\cdot r_{2n-1}}{a(n)+ r_{2n-1}}+r_{2n}$$

I've tried, but still can express it as a non recursive sequence.

Comment: I think your notation is misleading: your use of the forward slash '/' indicates division.  I think you want a vertical strike, indicating set-builder notation.  In latex, this may be rendered as '\vert'.

Also, your use of the inclusion symbol $\in$ is probably not what you intend, as it would mean that the whole set is an element of $R$.  Instead, I think you mean that each $r_i$ is an element of $R$.  You could use $\subseteq$ ('\subseteq') in place of $\in$, or bring the $\in$ inside the set notation:

$\{r_i \in R \vert i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 2n \}$

Answer (score 0):

Normally when people ask about writing a sequence in a non-recursive form, they mean that they want a "closed-form" description of the sequence, so that they can calculate, for instance, $a(1000)$ without having to go through the first $999$ terms of the sequence first.

Without some information or structure regarding the elements $r_i$, however, it seems to me that no matter what, you'll have to loop through $999$ iterations of *something* in order to find $a(1000)$, because you have to treat $r_1$ through $r_{999}$ individually.  Therefore I do not think you'll be able to write down a closed-form solution (that doesn't include a symbol such as '$\Sigma$' or '$\ldots$' or something similar) without knowing something about the $r_i$ in advance.

However, if we had some additional information about the $r_i$, then maybe we could do something.  For example, if $r_i = 1$ for all $i$, then
$$
a(1) = 2
$$
$$
a(2) = \frac{2}{3} + 1 = \frac{5}{3}
$$
and in general,
$$
a(n+1) = \frac{a(n)}{1 + a(n)} + 1
$$
Notice that
$$
a(3) = \frac{13}{8}
$$
$$
a(4) = \frac{34}{21}
$$
$$
a(5) = \frac{89}{55}
$$
and in general
$$
a(n) = \frac{F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n}}
$$
where $F_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Fibonacci number (starting at $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1, F_3 = 2, \ldots$).  (Proof: by induction on $n$.)

Note that $a(n)$ approaches the golden ratio as $n$ approaches infinity!

Anyway, since there is a closed-form solution for the Fibonacci numbers, you would have a closed-form solution for $a(n)$.  But this depended on having some information about the $r_i$.